# How to set up simple hover buttons with block format?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am making SIMPLE hover buttons for a project I am working on. The code is mainly HTML and not much CSS is going on. So, as you can see, I have two buttons. The same images too. Just duplicated it.  If you care to manipulate the code to make it look less messy, please do so.

What I need help with is

1. How exactly can I make my buttons in block form so they all are going vertically, not horizontally in my code?
2. How do I move them around the screen (Ex: Top: 550px Left: 400px)? I am not talking about animation, just simple HTML coordinate moving.

```
.Button {
    position:relative;
    width:151px;
    height:56px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}
.Button img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.Button img.inactive:hover {
    opacity:0; 
}
```

```
<center>
    <img style="float:center;" src="http://magniq.webs.com/Tutorials/example.png">
    <div id="home" style="position: absolute; left: 373px; top: 35px; width: 385px; height: 485px; overflow: auto;">
        <iframe src="http://magniq.webs.com/Tutorials/iFrameHome.html" name="inlineframe" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
    <a href="http://fryimvu.altervista.org/TransitioningImageTutorial.html" target="inlineframe">
        <div id="ButtonA" class="Button">
            <img class="active" src="http://s30.postimg.org/bkqtapxx9/home1.png" />
            <img class="inactive" src="http://s27.postimg.org/rdats3xz3/home.png" />
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://fryimvu.altervista.org/TransitioningImageTutorial.html" target="inlineframe">
        <div id="ButtonB" class="Button">
            <img class="active" src="http://s30.postimg.org/bkqtapxx9/home1.png" />
            <img class="inactive" src="http://s27.postimg.org/rdats3xz3/home.png" />
        </div>
    </a>
</center>
```

P.S. I prefer my iFrame stay like an iFrame.

Comment: Please don't use `<center>` nor `<font>`, no matter what page you're developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking to do something like this with your images and buttons:

http://jsfiddle.net/k8nn83g9/9/

```
/**use this to position your button**/
#move{position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;}

/**set background image**/
.Button{background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/");background-repeat: no-repeat;}

/**fade image out to see other image**/
.Button img {

-webkit-transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.Button img.active:hover {
opacity:0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*1. How exactly can I make my buttons in block form so they all are going vertically, not horizontally in my code?*

Just add `display: block` to `.Button`

> `display: block` Displays an element as a block element like `<p>`

Check this out http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

---

*2. How do I move them around the screen (Ex: Top: 550px Left: 400px)?*

Just add `position: absolute` to `.Button`

> An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the
>   nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the
>   viewport, like fixed).
>   The `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties are used to position the element.

If you want the two buttons to move together add a wrapper around them and use `position: absolute` in it and use `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` to position it.

If you want position it relative to the screen use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`

> An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the
>   viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the
>   page is scrolled

Check this out http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Tried adding display: block; in my code before I posted this question, but it stayed the same - in a horizontal fomat...

Comment: That is because you have `float: left` on `.Button` I had not realized until now, just remove it.